# Add to cart & Photobox missing functionality (WP/WooCommerce/Custom Theme)

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce

I have the following problem:

The "Add to Cart" button isn't showing on the Single Product page on varied products (e.g. tshirts with different sizes), *but it is showing on normal products pages (e.g. Bags).*

Now, I also noticed that the normal photobox doesnt open: Normally you would click on the product image and get the image displayed in a small box, where you can look through them. 
*HINT:* Therefore the problem may lie in loading the Javascript?

Switching Themes to the storefront Theme by woocommerce solves the problem, but I failed to isolate the specific after hours. (I debugged Woocommerce, too, and the Systemsreport doesn't say anything interesting either).

Stangely it worked yesterday at the launch of our homepage, and today it doesn't. I did some minor changes, but rolling back to yesterdays' version didn't do the trick.

Page: 
[http://www.werteleben-clothing.de/wordpress/produkt/sweater-werte-leben/](http://Here's%20the%20Link:%20%20http://www.werteleben-clothing.de/wordpress/produkt/sweater-werte-leben/)

Answer (score 0):

I was missing this in my footer, and therefore the Plugin scripts failed to load.

```
<?php
    wp_footer();
?>
```

For others who experience similiar problems: Make sure you didn't overwrite your `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()` in your respective .php files.

Greetings,

Felix